Is it possible to make Windows git bash support chinese
I am trying to use curl (v8.6.0) to send the HTTP request to sever side under Windows git bash terminal. The server side is a Java spring boot application. When the curl JSON content contains Chinese words, the server side shows this error:
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xb2
  at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.guangdanet.youxue.admin.rest.vo.product.line.LineSaveReqVO["name"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:402)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:361)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1863)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:185)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:395)
    ... 175 common frames omitted

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xb2
  at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 11]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2477)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:750)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidInitial(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3712)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidChar(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3708)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishString2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2634)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishAndReturnString(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2560)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.getText(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:335)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:42)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:392)

The jackson was the default JSON parser for spring boot application, and this server side works fine with a Google Chrome xhr request, but failed with the curl request from Windows git terminal.
Am I missing something? It looks like this git bash has some encoding issue in Windows. What should I to to make the windows git bash support Chinese words?
This is the curl info:
curl 8.6.0(x86_64-w64-mingw32) 1ibcur1/8.6.0 schannel z1ib/1.3.1 brotli/1.1.0std/1.5.5 1ibidn2/2.3.7 1ibps1/0.21.5 1ibssh2/1.11.0
    Release-Date: 2024-01-31
    Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ipfs ipns lda2 ldaps mgtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
    Features: alt-svc AsynchDNs brotli HSTS HTTPS-prOXy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefileibz NTLM PSL SPNEGO SSL SSPI threadsafe UnixSockets zstd


that has exactly nothing to do with your bash, your windows or your terminal emulator… that's just a bug in your application. It's not clear whether it's the server side, or your client-side program, but these two ends have no robust understanding of each other's encoding. Which clearly is a bug, because JSON requires UTF-8 encoding. Curl only hands through the bytes it gets from the server, so it can't be to blame here, unless you specifically asked it to ignore the server's offered encoding (which again must be UTF-8 if the server is sending JSON).

I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug in the user's own application.

What's the actual curl command that's failing?

@MarcusMüller Actually this does look like it's related to the OP's terminal environment. I highly doubt that JsonParser has a bug decoding UTF-8 into unicode so it's unlikely to be server-side. And curl is the OP's client. So that pretty much leaves the terminal.

https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/10820

this is not a bug of the application, because the application was running fine in production env for years. that the encoding issue of the http reqeust send from windows bash terminal. the server side need utf-8 but the client did not send a valid utf8 content. this maybe tweak some config issue of the window git bash. @MarcusMüller

What am I missing?

this server side works fine with a Google Chrome xhr request, but failed with the curl request from Windows git terminal.
Am I missing something? It looks like this git bash has some encoding issue in Windows.

The point you are missing is almost certainly to do with you seeing Chinese characters in one window and assuming they are the same as Chinese characters in another.
Characters are represented as bytes, and there's more than one way to encode characters as bytes.
The software industry has almost entirely settled on using the encoding known as UTF-8.  But MS Windows has always been a bit slow to adopt this, and I believe the terminal still doesn't use it by default. (Windows users please correct me if I'm wrong)
I suspect your terminal may be set to Code Page 936 which will allow it to write Chinese characters. But only your terminal will know what those bytes mean, the rest of the software industry has moved on. Chrome will definitely use UTF-8 by default, and MS Windows will translate between them when you copy-paste.
To confirm, you can confirm with an MS Windows command named chcp. Try typing this at the terminal:
chcp

Try This
You can change your terminal to UTF-8 by setting it to code page 65001:
chcp 65001

 I am not a Windows user. Over the years, I've seen people complaining about MS Windows terminal not working well with UTF-8. If you have problems with Code Page 65001, you can ask about it on https://superuser.com/.

You might want to use some other name than "MS Windows terminal" for the old school console (assuming you're talking of the one started by cmd.exe and the like). There's a new "Windows Terminal" app which is much nicer: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

@muru good point. I don’t really know whether this is the terminal (cmd.exe) or powershell to blame. I assume code pages and chcp is applicable to the powershell and there is some interaction between powershell and whatever terminal app is used to communicate this for rendering and input. I’ll blow the dust of my windows laptop when I get some time and see if I can figure it out.

this issue was exactly what you are talking about, I am doubt about the git bash in windows and using locale command and the bash shows the lang was lang=c. that may means using the simple ansi c environment? I am not sure, so I try to tweak the config to use utf-8. it looks like works.
